# My attribute selector rule isn't working

Tags: css

I am trying to write a rule to style a navigation item bold when the user is on the page it refers to. I don't have access to the HTML for that page. The rule I have written to get around that issue is:

```
html link[href="http://www.stuff.com/tagged/patterns"] + a[href="/patterns"]  {
font-weight: bold; }
```

This does not work. Neither does it work using a * instead of the HTML or taking it away altogether, using a > instead of a + or taking it away altogether, or any combination of these options.

This however:

```
a[href="/patterns"] { 
font-weight: bold; }
```

does make the navigation item I want bold, but it is bold on all pages. Now I just need to get it bold on that one page only. However, I don't see anything else on that one page to refer to other than it's specific url. Is there anyway to write that rule and make it work using only the URL I have?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the markup to the question? It will help a lot to see what's goin on on that specific page, and perhaps what's going on on other pages, so we can see how to get the selector that works for you...

Comment: Just remove "+" sign.

Comment: Can you show the HTML? If the link is in the head and the anchor is in the body, you're out of luck; css won't be able to handle that.

Comment: Yes, the link is in the head and the anchor is in the body ... I thought that putting the HTML or * out front as well as adding an + in front of the selector would solve this issue with where the two were located in the DOM.

Is there no CSS solution for cases like this? Thanks again.

Comment: That's right, `+` and `~` only work for two elements that are in the same parent. There is no CSS-only way around that. If changing the HTML is not an option, can you use JavaScript?

Comment: I was hoping that putting the HTML out front of the rule would have set it as the parent for the head and body but I guess the head and body are their own parents regardless ... I was looking to see how far I could push the CSS and try and learn some things. I guess this is as far as I can push it.

Yes I'll have to look at some sort of JavaScript solution I think. Thanks for the help. @MrLister